# create a matrix with football player

Tags: python, numpy

I have two dataframes

One is called player and contains name of football players

```
player= ["David Gonzalez","Agustin Martinez","Jibrail Al-Hindi","Edward Cahill","Simon Becker","Paolo Imperiali","Amir Bahari","Guilherme Souza"]

player = pd.DataFrame(player)
```

I have another dataframe called football

| id | scorer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | David Gonzalez, Edward Cahill |
| 2 | Agustin Martinez,Brian McNamara |
| 3 | Agustin Martinez, Jibrail Al-Hindi |
| 4 | Edward Cahill,Guilherme Souza |
| 5 | Paolo Imperiali, Yannick Wagner |
| 6 | Simon Becker,Amir Bahari |
| 7 | Paolo Imperiali,Yannick Wagner |
| 8 | Amir Bahari,Guilherme Souza,David Gonzalez |
| 9 | Edward Cahill,Amir Bahari |
| 10 | Simon Becker |
| 11 | Amir Bahari |
| 12 | Paolo Imperiali,Simon Becker |
| 13 | Edward Cahill,Guilherme Souza |
| 14 | Edward Cahill,Amir Bahari |
| 15 | Simon Becker |
| 16 | Simon Becker |

the second dataframe called football shows, which players scored in which game.

Now I would like to create a matrix, which shows rows and columns of all players from dataframe player, with 1 if there is a game id were both have scored together, and 0 if they don't have a game which they scored together.

I did this.

```
np.zeros((player,scorer)
```

But I think I am in the wrong path, because I want a matrix which the columns and rows give the names of the player in player and have 1 or 0 as numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the players for a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = football['scorer'].str.split(',\s*').explode().loc[lambda s: s.isin(player[0])]
df2 = s.rename('row').to_frame().join(s.rename('col'))

out = pd.crosstab(df2['row'], df2['col']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

*NB. you get the number of goals in common, if you just want 0/1, add `.clip(upper=1)`.*

Output:

```
                  Agustin Martinez  Amir Bahari  David Gonzalez  Edward Cahill  Guilherme Souza  Jibrail Al-Hindi  Paolo Imperiali  Simon Becker
Agustin Martinez                 2            0               0              0                0                 1                0             0
Amir Bahari                      0            5               1              2                1                 0                0             1
David Gonzalez                   0            1               2              1                1                 0                0             0
Edward Cahill                    0            2               1              5                2                 0                0             0
Guilherme Souza                  0            1               1              2                3                 0                0             0
Jibrail Al-Hindi                 1            0               0              0                0                 1                0             0
Paolo Imperiali                  0            0               0              0                0                 0                3             1
Simon Becker                     0            1               0              0                0                 0                1             5
```

Comment: @Maurice this is to split the string on comma with optional (`*`) spaces (`\s`) afterwards

Comment: this is to keep only the players defined in the other dataframe, try to remove this command, you'll see that you have all players

Comment: Add: `.clip(upper=1).rsub(1)`